# Cannot plot with Cartopy: Incomplete shapefile definition error BUT .shp .shx and .dbf are all present

Tags: shapefile, conda, cartopy, pip

I used to plot maps with Cartopy, which actually used to work fine until now.
Recently, when adding the maps features to a plot (es. coastlines etc) I get this error:

> "ValueError: Incomplete shapefile definition in
> '/home/francesca/.local/share/cartopy/shapefiles/natural_earth/physical/ne_110m_coastline.shp'
> "

I have checked previous questions on this issue and verified that .shp .shx and .dbf are present. And in fact they are!
I am working within a CONDA env, with python 3.10.11 and I have installed (again) cartopy==0.22.0 with "pip install cartopy" .

I am stuck and cannot figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I don't use Cartopy so not an answer but you may try to read your shapefile with another software to see if it is corrupt (there are online viewer so no need to install anything), also unless you specify the projection some other way you may need to provide a .prj file.

Comment: Do you also have a .prj file?

Comment: Also the .prj files are there. Maybe the problem is the non compatibility with my matplotlib version (3.5.2)? I was trying to downgrade to cartopy 0.18.0, but I have to figure out how to.